# How to compare datagrid value to combobox item?

Tags: string, exception, combobox, datagrid, compare

```
  for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == comboBox2.Text)
     {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
     }
  }
```

I'm trying to compare datagrid string value with string item in combobox, but it gives me an exception

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == comboBox2.Text
```

Comment: Please could you provide the exception.

Comment: sure, the exception says NullReferenceException was unhandled, and I'm writing the code in the event:  private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)